# How to prevent Homebrew from installing a certain formula dependency?

Tags: homebrew

How to prevent Homebrew from installing a certain dependency formula when installing any future formulae? On my mac, python is provided by conda and I don't want duplicate pythons. Every time I install a python-dependent formula it gets automatically installed.

Answer (score 20):

First, have a look the dependencies you need for the formula. (use `brew deps --tree xpdf` for a tree view)

```
brew deps -n formula
dep1
dep2
```

Then install the dependencies you want manually.

```
brew install dep1
```

And finally install the formula using `--ignore-dependencies`.

```
brew install --ignore-dependencies formula
```

Comment: The brew commandline now complains that this option is unsupported, but it still worked for me.  Thanks!

Comment: The flag does nothing and has been removed https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/5967#issuecomment-478870868

Answer (score 2):

@Pau's answer worked for me. One thing to add is that `brew deps`
will show all dependencies including optional and already installed ones so it made it hard for me when there were more than a dozen.

I ended up using `brew info`

```
brew info openjdk
#... basic info
==> Dependencies
Build: autoconf ✘, pkg-config ✔
Required: giflib ✔, harfbuzz ✔, jpeg-turbo ✔, libpng ✔, little-cms2 ✔
==> Requirements
Build: Xcode ✘
Required: macOS >= 10.15 ✔
#... more info
```

Then the key part of the answer that @Pau pointed out is to install with

```
brew install --ignore-dependencies openjdk
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm modifying brew's code for it

```
diff --git a/Library/Homebrew/software_spec.rb b/Library/Homebrew/software_spec.rb
index 5d15185e..0bcb3cf4 100644
--- a/Library/Homebrew/software_spec.rb
+++ b/Library/Homebrew/software_spec.rb
@@ -191,6 +191,8 @@ class SoftwareSpec
   end
 
   def depends_on(spec)
+    # my-mod: ignore python|rav1e
+    return if spec.is_a?(String) && /^(python|rav1e)(@.*)?$/.match?(spec)
     dep = dependency_collector.add(spec)
     add_dep_option(dep) if dep
   end
```

Comment: IMO this is the actual answer to the question. OP requested a solution that works for any future formulae.